# where exactly is the void in this expression(dart/flutter/map)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a ternary operator to return a widget. While I'm doing so I'm getting a 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.'.Where exactly am I going wrong?`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final usrMap = {"name": "Tom", 'Email': 'tom@xyz.com'};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Tutorial',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Text Widget Tutorial'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: usrMap.forEach((k,v) => k=="name" ? Text('Hello World') : Text(k))
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the wonderful world of Flutter :)

**forEach** function as in any language does not return any values.
It just iterates over each entry of the object.

If you need to return anything while iterating - use **map()**.

```dart
usrMap.map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(
          key,
          key == "name" ? Text('Hello World') : Text(key),
        )).values.toList()
```

Since you iterate over a Map and you need a key - the function call is a bit more complex than with a simple array:

1. **map()** using key and value returning a new Map with MapEntries inside
2. Take values from the new Map
3. Convert them to a list and pass to the children of any Widget that can have multiple children inside (Column, Row, Stack, etc) and don't use widget which has single child property like Center or container.

```dart
final children = usrMap.map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(
          key,
          key == "name" ? Text('Hello World') : Text(key),
        )).values.toList()

return Column(
    children: children,
);
```

or you can use spread operator to do it without additional variables (which makes it less readable):

```dart
return Column(
    children: [
        ...usrMap.map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(
          key,
          key == "name" ? Text('Hello World') : Text(key),
        )).values,
    ],
);
```

Comment: Just a tip. It does not really make sense to do: `[ ...values.toList() ]` since `[ ... ]` will take an `Iterable` and take all elements to convert it into a `List`. So you should instead use `[ ...values ]` or `values.toList()`.

Comment: I tried to follow your solution by defining children separately. However, I am getting an error of the type "The instance member usrMap can’t be accessed in an initializer." Along with a warning "The type of 'children' can't be inferred because it refers to an instance getter, 'usrMap', which has an implicit type."

Comment: The code that i used:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final usrMap = {"name": "Tom", 'Email': 'tom@xyz.com'};
  final children = usrMap.map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(
          key,
          key == "name" ? Text('Hello World') : Text(key),
        )).values.toList();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Tutorial',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Text Widget Tutorial'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: children
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: @ShaunThomas final children = usrMap.map()... should be **inside of the build()** method.